# Install Android APK Programmatically

Tags: android

Now, I want to programmatically install another apk, which exists in my current apks' assets.
However, I can't copy the apk to sdcard first, because the sdcard doesn't mount.

Is there a possbile solution ? thanks.

Comment: what is ur question, how to mount the sdk or how to install the apk programmatically ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To install app programmatically use following code, you'll need user permission.

```
android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES
```

Code:

```
Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW) 
    .setData(Uri.parse("file:///path/to/your.apk")) 
    .setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive"); 
startActivity(promptInstall);
```